# I need to know how to sort this PHP array by 'post_title'

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I am working with a wordpress theme, and there is content populated on one of my pages by an array, "`$chunks`"

Here is how `$chunks` is initialized:

```
$chunks = array_chunk($args['exhibitors'], 5);
```

I've tried sorting using the following code, but it does not work.

```
function sortByOrder($a, $b) {
return $a['post_title'] - $b['post_title'];
}

usort($chunks, 'sortByOrder');
```

I don't think I am understanding how to access the string in `'post_title'`.

A `vardump` of `$chunks` yeilds the following (for the first entry in the array, so you can see the format):

```
array(1) { 
   [0]=> array(5) {  
           [0]=> object(WP_Post)#538 (24) { 
                 ["ID"]=>int(466) 
                 ["post_author"]=> string(1) "1" 
                 ["post_date"]=> string(19) "2016-01-20 20:46:50"
                 ["post_date_gmt"]=> string(19) "2016-01-20 20:46:50" 
                 ["post_content"]=> string(866) "For more than three 
                  decades, we have developed speakers and electronics to meet the demanding 
                  requirements of professional applications. But we also create 
                  technological advancements like Modeler® design software, the 
                  Auditioner® audio demonstrator and LT loudspeaker technology. These 
                  tools and innovations enable designers and consultants to create more 
                  accurate, reliable, and cost-effective solutions. Bose® Professional 
                  Systems is an entire division of engineers, trainers, technical 
                  specialists and sales support teams. We provide support to a worldwide 
                  network of dealers and installers. It includes product and technical 
                  information, marketing and demonstration materials, design resources 
                  and other materials and services. We help our dealers and installers 
                  take projects from start to finish and provide a high level of service 
                  after the job is done." 
                  ["post_title"]=> string(4) "Bose"
                  ["post_excerpt"]=> string(0) "" 
                  ["post_status"]=> string(7) "publish"
                  ["comment_status"]=> string(6) "closed"  
                  ["ping_status"]=> string(6) "closed" 
                  ["post_password"]=> string(0) "" 
                  ["post_name"]=> string(4) "bose" 
                  ["to_ping"]=> string(0) "" 
                  ["pinged"]=> string(0) ""
                  ["post_modified"]=> string(19) "2016-01-20 20:46:57"
                  ["post_modified_gmt"]=> string(19) "2016-01-20 20:46:57"
                  ["post_content_filtered"]=> string(0) "" 
                  ["post_parent"]=> int(0)
                  ["guid"]=> string(55) "XXXXX" 
                  ["menu_order"]=> int(0) 
                  ["post_type"]=> string(9) "exhibitor" 
                  ["post_mime_type"]=> string(0) ""
                  ["comment_count"]=> string(1) "0" 
                  ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" 
           }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think you would need to sort the array *before* chunking it.

```
$exhibitors = $args['exhibitors'];
usort($exhibitors, function($a, $b) {
    if ($a->post_title > $b->post_title) return 1;
    if ($a->post_title < $b->post_title) return -1;
    return 0;
});
```

Then you can chunk the sorted array:

```
$chunks = array_chunk($exhibitors, 5);
```

If I'm wrong about the order of sort/chunk, this comparison function should still work.

Remember that the comparison function for usort needs to return an integer, either negative, positive, or zero depending on the result of the comparison.

Subtracting one `post_title` from another like

```
return $a['post_title'] - $b['post_title'];
```

will most likely return `0`, because those strings will be cast to numbers for the subtraction, and unless they happen to start with numbers, you'll effectively be getting

```
0 - 0 = 0
```

so no sorting at all, basically

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've tried this approach, and get the following error: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type WP_Post as array

Comment: @user2977729 I updated the answer. Sorry, I hadn't noticed it was an array of objects at first.

Comment: Thank you! Worked great.